# No author details in pdf, from R-Markdown / LaTeX template

Tags: r, templates, rstudio, r-markdown, pandoc

I'm trying to create an R-Markdown template based on the BioMed Central LaTeX template (bmc-article.tex).

The bmc template files are available for download here and needless to say, they work just fine: https://www.biomedcentral.com/authors/tex

In particular, the author, address and note definitions work and produce the desired outcome.

I have replaced the example author, adresse and note definitions in the bmc-article.tex file to use that as a tex template. I have also removed most of the example-content in that file.

The definition examples in the bmc-article.tex, I have replaced with:

```
$for(author)$
  \author[%
    addressref={$author.addressref$}, %
    $if(author.corref)$corref={$author.corref$}, $endif$ %
    $if(author.noteref)$noteref={$author.noteref$}, $endif$ %
    email={$author.email$} %
  ]{\inits{$author.inits$}\fnm{$author.fnm$} \snm{$author.snm$}}
  $endfor$

  $for(address)$
  \address[id=$address.id$]{ %
    $if(address.orgname)$ \orgname{$address.orgname$}, $endif$ %
    $if(address.street)$ \street{$address.street$}, $endif$ %
    $if(address.postcode)$ \postcode{$address.postcode$}, $endif$ %
    $if(address.city)$ \city{$address.city$}, $endif$ %
    $if(address.cny)$ \cny{$address.cny$}$endif$ %
  }
  $endfor$

  \begin{artnotes}
    $for(notes)$
      \note[id=$notes.id$]{$notes.text$} % note, connected to author
    $endfor$
  \end{artnotes}
```

When 'knitr'ing the Rmd file, it is (as far as I can tell), converted into meningful tex, and I have perused the resulting tex file again and again looking for tex-errors, but find none.

E.g.:

```
author:
- fnm: "Soren"
  snm: "ONeill"
  inits: "S"
  addressref: "aff1"
  email: "sorens mail"
  corref: "aff1"
  noteref: "n1"
```

..becomes:

```
\author[%
    addressref={aff1}, %
    corref={aff1},  %
    noteref={n1},  %
    email={sorens mail} %
]{\inits{S}\fnm{Soren} \snm{ONeill}}
```

The resulting pdf file however is not correct. The superscript numbers which associate names with addresses is displayed as questionmarks and author details at the end of the article is missing altogether.

I fail to see any significant difference between the tex file created by pandoc (based on my Rmd file) and the original bmx template tex file.

The following is rather lengthy I know.

The Rmd example file

---

```
title: "Template testing"
author:
  - fnm: "Soren"
    snm: "ONeill"
    inits: "S"
    addressref: "aff1"
    email: "sorens mail"
    corref: "aff1"
    noteref: "n1"
  - fnm: "Lotte"
    snm: "ONeill"
    inits: "L"
    addressref: "aff2"
    email: "lottes mail"
address:
  - id: "aff1"
    orgname: "University of Southern Denmark"
    street: "Campusvej 55"
    postcode: "DK 5500"
    city: "Odense M"
    cny: "Denmark"
  - id: "aff2"
    orgname: "University of Southern Denmark"
    street: "Campusvej 55"
    postcode: "DK 5500"
    city: "Odense M"
    cny: "Denmark"
notes:
  - id: "n1"
    text: "Equal contributor"

date: "2 jun 2017"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    template: template.tex
    keep_tex: TRUE
---

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see rmarkdown.rstudio.com.
```

This is the template.tex file, which I have adapted from the downloaded bmc-article.tex file

```
%% BioMed_Central_Tex_Template_v1.06
\documentclass{bmcart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %unicode support
\def\includegraphic{}
\def\includegraphics{}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frontmatter}

    \begin{fmbox}
      \dochead{Research}
      \title{$title$}

      $for(author)$
      \author[%
        addressref={$author.addressref$}, %
        $if(author.corref)$corref={$author.corref$}, $endif$ %
        $if(author.noteref)$noteref={$author.noteref$}, $endif$ %
        email={$author.email$} %
      ]{\inits{$author.inits$}\fnm{$author.fnm$} \snm{$author.snm$}}
      $endfor$

      $for(address)$
      \address[id=$address.id$]{ %
        $if(address.orgname)$ \orgname{$address.orgname$}, $endif$ %
        $if(address.street)$ \street{$address.street$}, $endif$ %
        $if(address.postcode)$ \postcode{$address.postcode$}, $endif$ %
        $if(address.city)$ \city{$address.city$}, $endif$ %
        $if(address.cny)$ \cny{$address.cny$}$endif$ %
      }
      $endfor$

      \begin{artnotes}
        $for(notes)$
          \note[id=$notes.id$]{$notes.text$} % note, connected to author
        $endfor$
      \end{artnotes}

    \end{fmbox}% comment this for two column layout

    \begin{abstractbox}

      \begin{abstract} % abstract
      \parttitle{First part title} %if any
        Text for this section.

      \parttitle{Second part title} %if any
        Text for this section.
      \end{abstract}

      \begin{keyword}
        \kwd{sample}
        \kwd{article}
        \kwd{author}
      \end{keyword}

    \end{abstractbox}

  \end{frontmatter}

  %$body$

  \begin{backmatter}

  \section*{Competing interests}
    The authors declare that they have no competing interests.

  \section*{Author's contributions}
      Text for this section \ldots

  \section*{Acknowledgements}
    Text for this section \ldots

  \bibliographystyle{bmc-mathphys} % Style BST file (bmc-mathphys, vancouver, spbasic).
  \bibliography{bmc_article}      % Bibliography file (usually '*.bib' )

  \end{backmatter}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following tex file (I've instructed RStudio/pandoc to retain the tex file):

```
%% BioMed_Central_Tex_Template_v1.06
\documentclass{bmcart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %unicode support
\def\includegraphic{}
\def\includegraphics{}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frontmatter}

    \begin{fmbox}
      \dochead{Research}
      \title{Template testing}

            \author[%
        addressref={aff1}, %
        corref={aff1},  %
        noteref={n1},  %
        email={sorens mail} %
      ]{\inits{S}\fnm{Soren} \snm{ONeill}}
            \author[%
        addressref={aff2}, %
         %
         %
        email={lottes mail} %
      ]{\inits{L}\fnm{Lotte} \snm{ONeill}}

            \address[id=aff1]{ %
         \orgname{University of Southern Denmark},  %
         \street{Campusvej 55},  %
         \postcode{DK 5500},  %
         \city{Odense M},  %
         \cny{Denmark} %
      }
            \address[id=aff2]{ %
         \orgname{University of Southern Denmark},  %
         \street{Campusvej 55},  %
         \postcode{DK 5500},  %
         \city{Odense M},  %
         \cny{Denmark} %
      }

      \begin{artnotes}
                  \note[id=n1]{Equal contributor} % note, connected to author
              \end{artnotes}

    \end{fmbox}% comment this for two column layout

    \begin{abstractbox}

      \begin{abstract} % abstract
      \parttitle{First part title} %if any
        Text for this section.

      \parttitle{Second part title} %if any
        Text for this section.
      \end{abstract}

      \begin{keyword}
        \kwd{sample}
        \kwd{article}
        \kwd{author}
      \end{keyword}

    \end{abstractbox}

  \end{frontmatter}

  %\subsection{R Markdown}\label{r-markdown}

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax
for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on
using R Markdown see rmarkdown.rstudio.com.

  \begin{backmatter}

  \section*{Competing interests}
    The authors declare that they have no competing interests.

  \section*{Author's contributions}
      Text for this section \ldots

  \section*{Acknowledgements}
    Text for this section \ldots

  \bibliographystyle{bmc-mathphys} % Style BST file (bmc-mathphys, vancouver, spbasic).
  \bibliography{bmc_article}      % Bibliography file (usually '*.bib' )

  \end{backmatter}
\end{document}
```

The latex log file is rather lengthy (lots of stuff about Unicode char's etc), but this is possibly helpful

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `aff1thanks' on page 1 undefined on input line 19.

LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMS+cmss on input line 19.

LaTeX Font Info:    No file OMScmss.fd. on input line 19.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/cmss/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OMS/cmsy/m/n' instead
(Font)              for symbol `textdagger' on input line 19.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `aff2thanks' on page 1 undefined on input line 25.

\address@aff1=\toks21
\address@aff2=\toks22
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 46.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 46.

LaTeX Warning: Reference `aff1thanks' on page 1 undefined on input line 46.

No file template_test_1.bbl.

AED: lastpage setting LastPage

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/it' in size <8> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/sl' tried instead on input line 89.


Overfull \hbox (1.0pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
 [] 
 []

[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}

] (./template_test_1.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences
(Font)              up to 1.0pt have occurred.


LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.


LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
```

Of course, I have noticed the warning about "Reference `aff2thanks'", but find no such reference in the original bmx-article.tex

Again, I know this is long -- I apologize for that. I hope someone can make suggestions...

Comment: Your made conversion is fine. Just bmcart class style is tricky. On a front page can be outputted only one address and rest of them has to be outputted before bibliography. There is `\printaddresses` command hooked on `\thebibliography` which prints these address. You just need to make bibliography and all address references will appear.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Linuxss

Comment: I think this is moving forward now ...

The issue seems to be (as far as I can work it out) - that the style of bmcart is rather dependent on the use of a \bibliography section and the standard behaviour of pandoc is to replace markdown citations with text rather than a latex citation.

E.g. a markdown citation like [@author_1999] is parsed into {[}1{]} and a \hypertarget with the reference ... and I'm not running into another error: ! Undefined control sequence \hypertarget

Perhaps pandoc should just parse md citations into latexs citations instead of text and hypertargets :-)

Comment: ..and apparently this can be accomplished using the --biblatex flag with pandoc ... I'll give that a try

Comment: with 

    pandoc in_file.Rmd --biblatex --template template.tex -o out_file.tex

I now get a tex file with correct citation and bibliography commands

    \autocite{aids_1976}

    \bibliographystyle{bmc\_mathphys.bst} 
    \bibliography{references.bib}

However pdflatex throws up:

    LaTeX Warning: Reference `aff1thanks' on page 1 undefined on input line 19.

Comment: Did you run bibtex <jobname>.tex? If no then run bibtex, pdflatex, pdflatex  on your project.

Comment: Yes -- I'm not having much luck :-(
I've uploaded some files here:     http://89.239.194.138:8000/d/040074c2ef/

From R, I can 
    _knitr::knit("template_test_1.Rmd")_
and it produces a valid template_test_1.md

With pandoc I can: 
    _pandoc template_test_1.md --biblatex --template template.tex -s -o template_test_1.tex_
and it produces a valid tex file

But no combination of 
    _pdflates template_test_1.tex_
and
    _bibtex template_test_1_
will produce the desired outcome

Comment: pandoc -s --bibliography=foo.bib --biblatex -o foo.tex foo.md
pdflatex foo.tex
bibtex foo.aux
pdflatex foo.tex
pdflatex foo.tex
Running this sequence of commands  what errors do you get?

Comment: Minimal working example files are [http://89.239.194.138:8000/f/cc01eecf54/?raw=1](here). 

Error from pdflatex is [https://pastebin.com/QBeujty7](here)

Error from bibtex is [https://pastebin.com/scXp5L3c](here)

Comment: Hmpfrr .. now working links
http://89.239.194.138:8000/f/cc01eecf54/?raw=1
https://pastebin.com/QBeujty7
https://pastebin.com/scXp5L3c

Comment: For reference -- Linuxss pointed out the \autocite command in the tex file is not recognized by latex/bibtex. When manually replacing it with \cite it works. I'm not entirely sure why pandoc inserts \autocite rather than \cite but I'll post here, if I find an answer

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share the fruits of your labour to https://github.com/rstudio/rticles? I would really like to use it.